# React Full Stack: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking to figure out what I'm doing wrong here however i'm not entirely sure. I am looking to pass down an object from the site, which is 'colour' as per the database (Australian).

I then want to map this array to the front end to only display these colours as such. E.g this array has ["White", "Black", "Red"] etc.

Initially I have a `useEffect` function, as below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getProduct = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await publicRequest.get("/products/find/" + id);
      setProduct(res.data);
    } catch {}
  };
  getProduct();
}, [id]);
```

From this, I am attempting to map:

```
<Filter>
  <FilterTitle>Colour</FilterTitle>
  {product.color.map((c)=> (
    <FilterColour color={c} key={c}/> 
  ))}
</Filter>
```

But I receive the classic:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

I've tried both colour, color etc, but cannot resolve? Any ideas Stack!

Comment: Initial state will probably be an empty array and you can't iterate over a colour array of a product if the product doesn't exist. There are a couple of ways to resolve this but I prefer to add in a check before the return. Something like: `if (!product.color) return <div>No product</div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Before it calls setProduct your default value should have color as its property and it needs to be an array. If you're facing this after setProduct is called just check res.data to see if you're getting data in the format you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data you are attempting to render is the result of an asynchronous function, `product` is still not populated during the initial render, it gets populated only after.

What we usually do in React to circumvent this, is adding conditional statements.

This should do the trick -

```js
<Filter>
  <FilterTitle>Colour</FilterTitle>
  {product.color && product.color.map((c)=> (
    <FilterColour color={c} key={c}/> 
  ))}
</Filter>
```

Comment: Ahhh @tomleb3, incredible! This works, thankyou so much. So the logic here is basically, if product.color exists, then map product.color across? Didn't even think of it!

Comment: You're very welcome. And yes, it basically means that during the initial render, `product.color` doesn't exist, because the data from `publicRequest.get` has not yet returned, and therefor we use this logic you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the attribute that you want to access keeps the same data structure. If not, you need to check whether it is undefined or not.

Solution 1:

Keep the same data structure. The useState hook should be initialized as:

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({color: []})
// or populate other attributes in the initial state.
```

Solution 2:
Check if the data exists:

```
{product.color && product.color.map((c)=> (
  <FilterColour color={c} key={c}/> 
))}
```